# Can I process incoming transfers from the daemon RPC?

Tags: daemon, transaction-data, rpc, transfer

Can I process incoming transfers using only the daemon RPC and my private view key (so without a wallet)? Or how can I decrypt `vout` from the `get_block` output JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The daemon (`monerod`) has no wallet functionality, it's for working with the blockchain. To determine incoming transactions for a given wallet (e.g. viewable and spendable using your wallet keys), you would need to scan the blockchain for outputs owned by your wallet and check their spent status.

A full scan (in pseudo code) looks something like follows (ignoring subaddresses):

```
unspent = [] # array which will hold tuples of (tx, output)
a = hex2bin(v) # my private view key
A = hex2bin(V) # my public view key
b = hex2bin(s) # my private spend key
B = hex2bin(S) # my public spend key

for each block in blockchain:
    for each tx in block:
        R = get_tx_pubkey(tx)
        for each output, i in tx:
            if is_mine(output, R, i) and not is_spent(output, R, i):
                unspent.append((tx, output))

is_mine(out, R, i):
    P = Hs(8aR||i)G + B
    return P == out

is_spent(out, R, i):
    x = Hs(8aR||i) + b
    I = xHp(xG)
    return has_key_image(blockchain, I)

get_tx_pubkey(tx):
    return key from tx.extra
```

Given the blockchain is hundreds of thousands of blocks each with N transactions, a full scan is pretty intensive.

Also, you cannot perform the above with just the daemon RPC method [get_block](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block), because other than the miner tx, [get_block](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block) will only get you the tx *hashes* - not the actual tx data. Therefore you'd also need to use [get_transactions](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions). And of course, calling these JSON methods repeatedly over the *whole blockchain* would be very slow.

If you are looking to develop your own wallet implementation, there are the necessary *binary* methods, which remove the JSON parsing overhead, but really, this is why there is a *wallet* RPC interface - `monero-wallet-rpc`. That handles all the lower-level stuff and exposes a useful RPC interface for higher-level wallet functionality.

If you just want to process a single blocks transactions, with only the daemon JSON RPC interface and your wallet keys, you can use [get_block](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block) (to get each tx hash) and [get_transactions](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions) (to get the tx pubkey and outputs for each tx). Then you'd need to implement a method like `is_mine` above to check if you owned a given output and a method like `is_spent` above to check the spent status (and for `has_key_image` you could make use of [is_key_image_spent](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#is_key_image_spent)).

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will try this way. Can you provide code written by (JS, Python, etc) for one function, maybe for `Hs(8aR||i)G + B`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For that single line you'll need an ed25519 library for the point multiplications and something that can do a Keecak hash. Look in the various projects at https://github.com/monero-ecosystem and see which libraries they use.

Comment: Further [explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/dmwdx0/as_a_receiver_how_do_i_get_an_output_of_a/f5nsgyk?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).